# How can I check which ports are in use from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, port

I'm running a Node.JS application and need to figure out if something is using a certain port.

How can I do this from the linux command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a more elegant way, but when in a hurry, I just run `netstat | grep port_number`

---

Yes, there are more elegant ways...

[Linux List The Open Ports And The Process That Owns Them](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-display-open-ports-owner.html)

```
sudo lsof -i
sudo netstat -lptu
sudo netstat -tulpn
```